# Пароль в терминале

Tags: ubuntu

Пытался найти ответ в нете, но везде разбирается только случай с отсутствием символов при наборе пароля. Меня озадачил мой товарищ, которому я установил ОС на основе Ubuntu. У него вообще не вводится пароль. Пароль очень простой - 2 раза одна буква, перепутать сложно. Т.е. он нажимает эту букву 2 раза, потом ENTER и терминал просит ещё раз ввести пароль. И так бесконечно... Что это может быть и как исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может, пароль на самом деле неверный? Раскладка не та? Капслок не тот?

Comment: Спрашивал у него про это. Говорит, что делал всё как обычно. Значит Вы тоже с этим не сталкивались?

Comment: Бесконечно не должно просить, 3 попытки вроде как дается.

Comment: Да да, Вы правы 3 попытки. Бесконечно я имел в виду проблему, которая не пропадает. Попробую ещё его попытать. Может дело с раскладкой. Спасибо Вам за быстрый отклик!

Comment: Кстати, раз уж я Вас нашёл, не подскажете можно ли на 32 битную систему Скайп в наше время установить? Про браузерный вариант я знаю. Я про программу. ОС - Zorin 32 bit.